# Inconsistent native Array.sort() behavior in JS

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort an array of integers by moving all elements with a value of 2 or greater to the end of the array. However, if I'm comparing two elements that are both 2 or greater, or that are both less than 2, then I want to keep them in their current order. I'm using the following comparison function with the native `.sort()`:

```
function customSort(a, b) {
  return (a >= 2 && b < 2) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

It seems to work as intended for the following cases:

```
[2, 3, 2, 0] => [0, 2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] => [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2]
```

But it looks like once I get past 10 elements, it seems to randomly order the elements that are less than 2, and the elements that are 2 or greater:

```
[2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2]
                (expected result) => [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2]
```

I assumed the `-1` in the ternary operator would always keep the left element left and thus keep the order (as opposed to `0` which would understandably order them randomly). I'm aware there's a better way to sort without using the native `.sort()`, but I'm just curious about the behavior and if there's some way I could change the comparison function to get this working correctly with the native `.sort()`.

Comment: What you call "native" is actuallly built–in (a [*built–in function*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-built-in-function) or a [*built–in method*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-built-in-method)). Prior to ECMAScript 2015, a [*native object*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.6) (which includes functions and methods) was something you might write in javascript, however that term seems to have been replaced in the latest specification with [*ordinary object*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object). ;-)

Comment: @RobG thanks, I'm never too sure what the correct term for it is, but good to know!

Comment: That's OK, the language specification is changing very fast at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some console logging of what happens in the `sort` method and I've come to the conclusion that when the sort iterates over the array, it will reiterate over any elements that have moved position again with your comparison function. The fact that your conditional is a bit more specific, and in a large array makes it very hard to keep track of what's going on. I've used your first example and logged the result of the ternary operator and the array as it's being sorted. You get the following:

```
 [2, 3, 2, 0]
 -1
 [2, 3, 2, 0]
 -1
 [2, 3, 2, 0]
 1
 [2, 3, 2, 2]
 1
 [2, 3, 3, 2]
 1
 [0, 2, 3, 2]
```

When you sort through `[2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`, it goes through 29 iterations. When you add that extra 0 at the end of the array, it goes through 58 iterations. During that extra 29 I'd imagine it'll shuffle the elements backwards and forwards using your conditionals. That may explain why you're not getting the results you expect.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I did try console.logging but didn't look closely at the number of iterations; I guess I'll have to look out for this when using the built-in sort

Comment: I was curious to see how the sorting was done. In the past Ive always used a simple ```a-b``` function to sort my arrays. Once I saw that the initial example went through 6 iterations (in my mind I was thinking 3-4), I had to delve a bit deeper.

Answer (score 2):

A way to do it without sorting is to loop over it and append items greater that one to one array and other items to another and join them.

```
var arr = [2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var shifted = [].concat.apply([],arr.reduce( function (arr, val, ind){ 
                                                 var ind = val > 1 ? 1 : 0;
                                                 arr[ind].push(val); 
                                                 return arr;
                                              },
                                              [[],[]]));
```

Comment: Thanks, I was definitely going to do it another way instead of the .sort, but I'm really just wondering why the .sort is producing this inconsistent behavior

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to epascarello's answer, only it uses *reduceRight* to loop over the array backwards. Where a member `>=` 2 is encountered, it's spliced and pushed to the end of the array.

This should be efficient as the array is modified in place, no new array is created whereas epascarello's creates 6 additional arrays (including the result of *concat*).

```js
var data = [2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0].reduceRight(function(acc, n, i, data) {
  if (n >= 2) data.push(data.splice(i, 1));
  return data;
}, null);

document.write(data); // [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Looks like this still has to reduce the spliced arrays to elements with `data.splice(i, 1)[0]`, and the spliced elements would be ordered backwards: `[2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] => [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2]`. But thanks, I definitely still learned from the use of `reduceRight` for a reverse traversal